# interaction between WSL (i.e. ubuntu on Windows) and ffmpeg

Tags: linux, ffmpeg, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm considering migrating some FFMPEG workflows to the Windows Subsystem for Linux ([WSL2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Subsystem_for_Linux)), but it's a nontrivial amount of work so I wanted to see if anyone has experience here, specifically whether or not the hardware encoding functionality works through the abstraction layer.

For instance, if QSV or NVENC/CUDA can work just as if they were run on a fully native linux environment while in WSL2, that's great.  If none of it works that's great as well (because I won't bother)... if some stuff works, I'll need to ask what people have and have not gotten to work before I decide.  ;)

Comment: In summmary QSV, NVENC don't work fully native. Nvidia had to develop I custom driver for wsl. As far I can tell QSV is not supported yet nor anything else that needs I real native gpu.